# update node attribute with latest datetime in XML

Tags: xml, regex, perl, datetime

I have below XML:

```
< measCollecFile>

    < fileHeader>

            < measCollec beginTime="2013-03-14T12:10:00+00:00" />

    </ fileHeader>

    < measData>

            < measInfo>
                    < granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2013-03-14T12:15:00+00:00"  />
                    < measType>VS.ave</measType>
                    < measType>VS.aveCPU</measType>

                    < measValue>VS1</measValue>
                    < measValue>VS2</measValue>
            </ measInfo>
    </ measData>
</ measCollecFile>
```

Q: My Problem I need to process this XML file and modify few data in certain Elements. I am able to do that with the help of this site as you can see from my previous posts.

There is a new challenge. as you can see there is datetime element in the XML as well. And I need to update this to the current datetime in the same format as it appears in the XML. i.e. the XML will always contain any date and I just to find the datetime tag and update it to the current datetime but it should be in the same format as it is in there.

Shall I take it as separate issue and treat as simple regex Perl problem and resolve accordingly as a flat file **find and replace problem**?

or **LIBXML** has anything built into to identify the datetime Tag and update it with latest datetime?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything special to identify a "datetime" tag as you mean it.  You certainly could look for attributes that fit a specific format, but is that really what you want?

Using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to replace the beginTime with the current date:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use Time::Piece;

my $date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $data);

for my $node ($dom->findnodes('//*[@beginTime]')) {
    if ( my $begin = $node->getAttribute('beginTime') ) {
        my ($plaindate, $tz) = split '(?=\+)', $begin;
        my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($plaindate, $date_format);
        print "old beginTime = '$date'\n";
        my $newdate = localtime->strftime($date_format);
        $node->setAttribute('beginTime', $newdate . $tz);
    }
}

print $dom->toString();

__DATA__
<measCollecFile>
    <fileHeader>
        <measCollec beginTime="2013-03-14T12:10:00+00:00" />
    </fileHeader>
    <measData>
        <measInfo>
            <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2013-03-14T12:15:00+00:00"  />
            <measType>VS.ave</measType>
            <measType>VS.aveCPU</measType>
            <measValue>VS1</measValue>
            <measValue>VS2</measValue>
        </measInfo>
    </measData>
</measCollecFile>
```

To update both beginTime and endTime, you could create a more complicated xpath:

```
my @attribs = qw(beginTime endTime);
my $attribs_list = join ' | ', map {'@'.$_} @attribs;

for my $node ($dom->findnodes("//*[$attribs_list]")) {
    for my $key (@attribs) {
        if ( my $att = $node->getAttribute($key) ) {
            my ($plaindate, $tz) = split '(?=\+)', $att;
            my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($plaindate, $date_format);
            print "old $key = '$date'\n";
            my $newdate = localtime->strftime($date_format);
            $node->setAttribute($key, $newdate . $tz);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Miller. you rock!!  This is exactly what I want.  The only problem is there may be multiple occurrences of beginTime and endTime and it might occur at different depths. But I will know before hands few things: what are the Tag names like beginTime,endTime etc. and the formats of the datetime as well. Hope the findnode still works to find all beginTime at all the depths in the XML. I might have delta time differences between the begin and end times which I need to maintain at all times.

Comment: The xpaths I provided will find all nodes with the said attributes.  As long as you can program the change logic that you want, these should work.

Comment: not sure but the second one does not work where I include both the nodes qw(beginTime endTime) . The find node is not finding anything?

Comment: oops Yes it does work! Actually I used parse_file instead of load_xml. Since I had to update many other fields as well. So seems like I need to do this twice once with parse_file and the next with load_xml for datetime?

Comment: The method for loading the xml is inconsequential.  I just used load_XML because it enabled me to create a working example.

Comment: It works both ways actually. i maid some silly mistakes! all is good. thanks for your help

Comment: actually the datetime can also appear directly in the node like <mtime>2013-03-14T12:10:00+00:00</mtime> So obviously this code will not work.

Comment: so essentially I need to find a list of nodes instead of list of attributes

Comment: If your XML::LibXML is recent enough, you can do `my $att = $node->{$key}` and `$node->{$key} = $newdate.$tz` as a shortcut for `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.