# update node text with datetime in XML

Tags: xml, perl, datetime, libxml2

I have the XML:

```
< measCollecFile>
    < fileHeader>
        < measCollec>2013-03-14T12:10:00+00:00</measCollec>
    </ fileHeader>
    < measData>
        < measInfo>
            < granPeriod>2013-03-14T12:15:00+00:00</granPeriod>
            < measType>VS.ave</measType>
            < measType>VS.aveCPU</measType>
            < measValue>VS1</measValue>
            < measValue>VS2</measValue>
        </ measInfo>
            < granPeriod>2013-03-14T12:15:00+00:00</granPeriod>
    </ measData>
</ measCollecFile>
```

I did ask a [similar query earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22954578/1733163) and got the reply from Miller. This is slightly different. And this time I need to update the datetime on node instead of attributes.

A list of node provided `qw(measCollec granPeriod)`. and we need to update the current datetime in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to answer my own question. THe credit still goes to Miller!!

```
 my @attribs = qw(measCollec granPeriod);

 my $attribs_list = join ' | ', map {$_} @attribs;

 NODE: for my $node ($dom->findnodes("//*[$attribs_list]")) {

    for my $key (@attribs) {
        my @titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName($key);
            foreach my $t (@titles) {

            my ($plaindate, $tz) = split '(?=\+)', $t->textContent;
            my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($plaindate, $date_format);
            print "old $key = '$date'\n";
            my $newdate = localtime->strftime($date_format);

                my $newrNode=XML::LibXML::Element->new($key);
                $newrNode->addChild($dom->createTextNode($newdate));
                $node->replaceChild($newrNode,$t);

        }
    }
last NODE; # ending the loop otherwise it will cascade again.

}

print $dom->toString();
```